# Irregular border on boxes displayed on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a nav bar which correct aspect is this you can see here (FROM FIREFOX):

[image: A]

When I open the same page on Chrome, as I move window height and width manually, the right borders you see in each section appear and dissapear as if this was some kind of resolution problem (they are there, but sometimes are not shown). So I get things like this (FROM CHROME):

[image: B]

or this (FROM CHROME):

[image: C]

This DOES NOT happen on Firefox, as I can change window's size to any size, and all borders keep on showning.

EDIT: I have tried to reproduce this on jsFiddle but it seems to work fine opening this both from Firefox and Chrome, my problem is not happening in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qS9gQ/1/

Code HTML:

```
<nav>
<a href="#slide1" class="icon-hola"><span>¡HOLA!</span></a>
<a href="#slide2" class="icon-experiencia"><span>EXPERIENCIA</span></a>
<a href="#slide3" class="icon-metodo"><span>TV / MEDIOS</span></a>
<a href="#slide4" class="icon-entrenamos"><span>SERVICIOS</span></a>
<a href="#slide5" class="icon-contacto"><span>CONTACTO</span></a>
</nav>
```

Code CSS:

```
body, html { padding: 0; margin: 0; font-size: 100%; height:100%;}

body {
   background-color: white;
   width:100%; height:100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   font-family: "Lato", Arial;
   font-weight:300;
}
*, *:after, *:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;  
}

.cbp-contentslider nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 3.313em;
    z-index: 1000;
    border-top: 1.5px solid grey;
    overflow: hidden;
        text-align:center;
}

.cbp-contentslider nav a {
    padding-left: 3.125em;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: grey;
    outline: none;
    line-height: 3;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-right: 1.5px solid grey;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: If the problem is unreproducible, cut out a line in css one by one until you can find which one (or multiple) are causing this problem

Comment: I am abouyt to try. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

What's the point of using border as 1.5px width? Maybe this is the problem? Browser can't render sometimes properly this width, try to set it to 1px, maybe this will help, cant't test it though cause on fiddle everything is fine.

Comment: Ok another one problem could be because of "overflow: hidden", you have padding-left in em, so I suppose sometimes browser can render block one on another, and this is why border is not shown. I suggest you to add 'margin-right: 2px' to your 'a' elements and see if that work. If that will not help either, try to remove 'outline' out of css.